# How to get munin to alert for NaN

Tags: mysql, monitoring, munin

I am using [this mysql slave status plugin](http://munin-monitoring.org/attachment/wiki/plugin-mysql_slave_status/mysql_slave_status) and on the munin master I have added...

```
mysql_slave_status.warning 30
mysql_slave_status.critical 60
```

So it alerts whenever the slave gets behind the master. How do I get munin to alert me (critical alert if possible) when the plugin returns "NaN", will it do that automatically?

It returns NaN when the SQL isn't running or the connection fails.

EDIT: In the end I made it add a large number to the actual value if the connection was down.

Comment: I'm kinda surprised that munin doesn't do this automatically...

Answer (score 0):

Having written a bit of the [mysql_](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/master/plugins/node.d/mysql_#L86) plugin I can attest to having replaced much of the single purpose plugins of munin. In the above link there is a documented example of what you want:

```
[mysql_replication]
env.slave_io_running_warning 0.5
env.slave_sql_running_warning 0.5
env.seconds_behind_master_warning 300
env.seconds_behind_master_critical 600
```